# How to create a report with hyperlinks that open relative files in Python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, href

I would like to generate a report with reference links to local files using relative paths. I want this to run on my *nix system and the Windows machines used by others. I have tried the following:

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame(['<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>'])
df.to_html('file.html')
```

For some reason this does not render the `href` for me. I have tried it in multiple browsers and none render the html.

How can I generate a report using python which includes hyperlinks to open files using local paths? I would like this document to be able to be used by others without running `python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the tags.

`df.to_html(pth,escape=False)`